# How to control colors in twoway

Tags: plot, colors, stata

Say that I have these data:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
gen hours1 = inrange(hours, 1, 20)
replace hours1 = 2 if inrange(hours, 21, 39)
replace hours1 = 3 if inrange(hours, 40, 40)
replace hours1 = 4 if inrange(hours, 41, 80)
collapse (mean) wage, by(grade hours1)
```

I can plot them as follows:

```
twoway  (line wage grade if hours1==1) ///
        (line wage grade if hours1==2) ///
        (line wage grade if hours1==3) ///
        (line wage grade if hours1==4), ///
        legend(order(1 "1-20 Hours" 2 "21-39 Hours" 3 "40 Hours" 4 "41+ Hours"))
```

This produces:
[image]

I then make a similar figure, except that the first category (`hours1==1`) is omitted:

```
twoway  (line wage grade if hours1==2) ///
        (line wage grade if hours1==3) ///
        (line wage grade if hours1==4), ///
        legend(order(1 "21-39 Hours" 2 "40 Hours" 3 "41+ Hours"))
```

[image]

My question is how can I make the color scheme of the second plot be the same as that of the first plot? In other words, I would like to have the `21-39` group be red, the `40` group be green, and the `41+` group be yellow.

Comment: https://www.colourblindawareness.org/colour-blindness/types-of-colour-blindness/  Otherwise the simplest way is just to ask for specified colours.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. If you don't mind me asking, what is the easiest way to list the colors from a given color scheme so that I can know which colors to include? (I tried `graph query colorstyle`, but that didn't seem to give me what I need.)

Comment: It looks as if you're using Stata 18, in which case you get colours `stc1 stc2` etc, with the default scheme `stcolor`.